# Nativescript-ngx-slides : Unable to go to next or previous slides

Tags: nativescript

I am unable to navigate to Next or Previous slides, using Nativescript--ngx-slides plugin.

Is this feature not enabled ? If yes, then how to call these methods ?

When I use,

```
@ViewChild("slides") slides: SlidesComponent
```

Then in

```
NgAfterViewInit let slidesComponent =  <SlidesComponent>this.slides.nativeElement
```

I get an undefined error.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out, instead of ElementRef use SlidesComponent:

```
import { SlidesComponent } from "nativescript-ngx-slides";
...
```

and then

```
@ViewChild("slideContainer") slideContainer: SlidesComponent;
```

and then call the nextSlide() method:

```
onNextSlide() {
    this.slideContainer.nextSlide();
}
```

Cheers